# How to display the retrieved values in a label from a web page using Query String in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, query-string

I am writing a web application to retrieve a value from a textbox from one web page and display it in a label in another web page. I wrote a code to retrieve from one web page but I don't know how to display the retrieved values in another web page. 
  Here is the code

```
//This is the code in first web page
if (AuthenticateUser(Textusertbl1.Text, textpastbl1.Text)) 
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(Textusertbl1.Text, CheckBoxtbl1.Checked); 
    Response.Redirect("~/WelcomeStaff.aspx?myname=" + Server.UrlEncode(Textusertbl1.Text));
}
//This is code in 2nd web page.On the page load I need to display this retrieved values in a label      
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string myname = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["myname"]);
}
```

Could anyone tell me how to display the text in a LABEL.?I am new to .Net .Please help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a label on the page with ID "MyLabel"

```
MyLabel.Text = myname;
```

That would go in Page_Load right after your variable assignment.

Comment: I modified the code as  WelcomeUsername.Text = Request.QueryString["label"].ToString();  and it worked for me.!!Thanks a lot for spending your time to answer my question @trnelson

Comment: @anusha you're welcome! Please make sure you check the input also before writing to page (for null and malicious input by users). Also if my answer was helpful please consider marking it as the answer. All the best.